# Accessing dictionary value in an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

```
catArray-->
{
"category_logo" = "category_logo/blue.png";
"category_name" = "Health & Wellness";
id = 9;
}
```

I have to fetch the "category_name" in my tableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath  :    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"catCell";

    catCell=(catCell *)[tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(categoryTableCell==nil){
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CategoryTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    }


      ???????= [self.categoryListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      categoryTableCell.dataLabel.text = ??????

}
```

Please help me to set this in label text.  What do I write in place of question marks?

Comment: What you call "catArray" is a dictionary, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your catArray is an array of NSDictionaries it would look like this:

```
NSString *s= self.categoryListArray[indexPath.row][@"category_name"];

categoryTableCell.textLabel.text=s;
```

Comment: But what he shows on the first line is *not* an array.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense if it's not an array of dictionaries, so I just assumed that there was an array of those dictionaries instead of just one NSDictionary.

Comment: But that's probably the OP's first problem.

Comment: Could be, but given the name "categoryListArray" (which we don't see the definition of) I was willing to give OP the benefit of doubt. That's all.

Comment: I find that about 50% of the difficulties that newbies have with such structures is not understanding the difference between an array and a dictionary.  (Especially when dealing with JSON.)

Comment: thanks for answer... i am new in xocde..this is my first project .